# Add a serverside stored javascript file to html (node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm having a small problem with my project. 
I'm using node and express for a little webpage .. it is rendering the html page, but the javascript file (test.js) is not sent to the user ..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spektrum</title>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
        <style>
            canvas{     

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <!-- some stuff --> 
        </body> 
</html>
```

Node.js file:

```
var http = require('http'),  
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'), 
    app     = express(); 
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// ..... 
    app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

Any idea how to send the javascript file with the html file to the user?

Greetings, 
JS

Comment: Are you using Express' static middleware? If not, take a look at this: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `static` middleware to serve file (`test.js` needs to exist)

example:

```
// GET /javascripts/jquery.js
// GET /style.css
// GET /favicon.ico
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```